# Поиск кратчайшего пути

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, оптимизация, любой-язык

Нужно написать программу, которая принимает двумерный массив (квадратный), состоящий из чисел. Эти числа означают "стоимость", которая означает сколько стоит пройти по этой клетке. Программа начинает с верхнего левого угла и идет в правый нижний. Шагать можно только вниз или вправо. Нужно найти самый "дешевый" путь
Итак, примеры:

```
2    5

10   3
```

Ответ: `2 + 5 + 3 = 10`.

```
1   2   3

0   4   15

0   0   7
```

Ответ: `1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 7 = 8`.

Ответ может быть в любом языке программирования, главное для меня — понять принцип. Придумать алгоритм. Чем быстрее работает алгоритм и чем меньше его вычислительная сложность — тем лучше.

Comment: Чем помочь? Что у вас не получилось при реализации? За вас здесь никто ничего решать не будет, а алгоритм прост, рекурсивно ищете любые пути. После того как нашли первый у вас уже есть его стоимость. При прокладке новых путей, если стоимость нового пути больше уже найденной, просто путь отбрасываем

Comment: Волновой алгоритм, например... прост как валенок, а с учётом ограничений по направлениям так и вовсе тривиален. Причём чтобы **НЕ** найти готовый код в Инете - это надо постараться.

Comment: `Шагать можно только вниз или вправо` - вот это интереснее убрать)

Answer (score 4):

Словами устроит? :)

Идем из верхнего левого угла и ставим в первом ряду каждой клетке стоимость как сумму клеток слева от нее + она сама (первая горизонталь достижима только слева).

Далее во второй крайняя слева - это сумма стоимости над ней + она сама (только сверху), а все прочие - минимальное значение пути сверху и слева.

И так до конца... Словом, простое динамическое программирование.

Сейчас попробую набросать на C++.

Вот, на коленке, раз уж вас любой язык устраивает... Путь выводится в обратном порядке - от правого нижнего в левый верхний:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int val[3][3] =
{
    1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 15, 0, 0, 7
};

int cost[3][3] = { 0 };
int pred[3][3] = {-1};   // 0 - бўҐаег, 1 - б«Ґў 


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cost[0][0] = val[0][0];
    for(int c = 1; c < 3; ++c)
    {
        cost[0][c] = cost[0][c-1] + val[0][c];
        pred[0][c] = 1;
    }
    for(int r = 1; r < 3; ++r)
    {
        cost[r][0] = cost[r-1][0] + val[r][0];
        pred[r][0] = 0;
        for(int c = 1; c < 3; ++c)
        {
            if (cost[r-1][c] < cost[r][c-1])
            {
                cost[r][c] = val[r][c] + cost[r-1][c];
                pred[r][c] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                cost[r][c] = val[r][c] + cost[r][c-1];
                pred[r][c] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Total cost: " << cost[2][2] << endl;
    int r = 2, c = 2;
    for(;;)
    {
        cout << "(" << r << "," << c << ") - ";
        if (pred[r][c]) --c; else --r;
        if (r == 0 && c == 0)
        {
            cout << "(0,0)\n";
            break;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: интересный алгоритм, вероятно самый оптимальный! я проверил варианты матриц 4x4 - все примеры решены правильно, но пока трудно поверить до конца - поищу еще подвох надосуге :-)

Comment: В расчете total cost вы ошиблись только, а шаги правильные выдает

Comment: В смысле ошиблись в расчёте? Можно тест?

Comment: @EugeneBartosh Не вижу, откровенно говоря. Покажите (хотя бы на примере, если не ошибку в коде).

Comment: Ну я немного ваш код преобразовал, для случая N-мерной матрицы, общую сумму так вывожу - cout << "Total cost: " << cost[K-1][K-1] << endl; - она там неправильная когда K>3

Comment: @EugeneBartosh Все, после слов **"я немного ваш код преобразовал"** вопрос снят. Не обижайтесь, но напоминает - "-Этот Паваротти... что им так восхищаются? Ни слуха, ни голоса... - А где ты его слушал? - Да мне Гогия немного напел на днях..."

Comment: чо ноту я папуталь? до без диеза лупанулъ? :-) ну я так понимаю что Total cost в правой нижней ячейке должен возникнуть, так? ну так и в чем моя ошибка - беру cost[K-1][K-1], могу код прислать только не в комментах наверно

Answer (score 1):

Рекурсивная вариация на тему волнового алгоритма:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE_X = 3;
const int SIZE_Y = 3;
const int PATH_LEN = SIZE_X+SIZE_Y-1;

struct {int x; int y;} path[PATH_LEN] = {0, 0};

int map[SIZE_Y][SIZE_X] = {
    1, 2, 3, 
    0, 4, 15, 
    0, 0, 7
};


int find(int x, int y) {
    int self = map[y][x];
  if (x == SIZE_X-1 && y == SIZE_Y-1) {
      path[PATH_LEN - 1].x = x;
      path[PATH_LEN - 1].y = y;

      return self;
  }
  if (x == SIZE_X-1) {
      return self + find(x, y + 1);
  }
  if (y == SIZE_Y-1) {
      return self + find(x + 1, y);
  }
  int NEXTSTEP = x + y + 1;
  int down = find(x, y + 1);
  int right = find(x + 1, y);

  if (down < right) {
      path[NEXTSTEP].x = x;
      path[NEXTSTEP].y = y+1;
  } else {
      path[NEXTSTEP].x = x+1;
      path[NEXTSTEP].y = y;
  }

  return self + min(down, right);
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Result: " << find(0, 0) << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < PATH_LEN; ++i)
        cout << "<" << path[i].x << ", " << path[i].y << ">" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

задача сложная, может быть например такой массив

```
1 1 1
2 2 9
1 1 1
```

если сразу пойти по дешевому пути - по строке 1 - то остаток пути придется пройти по самому дорогому - с 9-кой. 
Или еще пример

```
8 8 8 8 8
8 9 9 9 8
8 9 7 9 8 
8 9 9 9 8 
8 8 8 8 8
```

Несмотря на то, что 7-ка является самой привлекательной по цене - чтобы пройти чере нее, придется преодолеть 2 9-ки (это на тему "не гонялся бы ты поп за дешевизной" :-)
В матрице 1000x1000 или больше таких коллизий будет великое множество.

По сути других вариантов, кроме фрактальной рекурсии, я не вижу, вычислительная сложность алгоритма очень высокая. 
Фрактальные алгоритмы используются для сжатия изображений, написано множество научных работ по [оптимизации этих алгоритмов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_compression).

Comment: От вас не требуются ВСЕ варианты. Моя программа за O(n) (если n - число всех элементов матрицы :)) дает путь по восьмеркам - по горизонтали, потом по вертикали. Можно и наоборот - по вертикали, потом по горизонтали :) Стоимость - 72.

Comment: да у вас крутой алгоритм, я его еще не осознал в деталях когда свой ответ писал :-)